# The houses on one side of a road are numbered using consecutive even numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> The houses on one side of a road are numbered using consecutive even numbers. The sum of the numbers of all the houses in that row is 170. If there are at least 6 houses in that row and $a$ is the number of the sixth house, then
>   (A) $2 ≤ a ≤ 6$
>   (B) $8 ≤ a ≤ 12$
>   (C) $14 ≤ a ≤ 20$
>   (D) $22 ≤ a ≤ 30$

I couldn't figure out a proper way of solving this, I tried guess-and-check but even that didn't really work. Can somebody give me a hint as to how I can start this?

Comment: Do you know how to add up $(a-2n)+(a-2 (n-1))+.... +(a-4)+(a-2)+a $?

Comment: You have n houses.  n >=6.  The houses are numbered a-2n,....,a-2,a.  The sum is 170.

Comment: @fleablood I do, but that only forms one equation...

Comment: @fleablood oh okay then we put the condition n>6 and find the value of a, am I right?

Comment: You won't be able to solve it.  But you can get a range.  If the sum is 170 that b puts an upper limit on a and n.  And n >= 6.

Comment: @fleablood yeah thats what I meant...the range of a. Thanks :)

Comment: Notice if a <= 12 the max the sum ca be is 12+10+8+6+4+2 so that's out.

Comment: @fleablood the first term you have given in the expression won't be there. The summation starts from a-2(n-1) and not a-2n

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed?

Comment: @jnyan I don't think so, else there would be a lot of solutions for a

Comment: I know, since it was not mentioned in the question, I was clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $k$ houses numbered $c,c+2,c+4,\dots,c+2(k-1)$. The sum of house numbers is
$$kc+k(k-1)=k(c+k-1)=170=2\cdot5\cdot17$$
$k$ is a factor of 170, and the constraint $k\ge6$ limits it to the following numbers:
$$10,17,34,85,170$$
Since the sum of increments $0+2+4+\cdots+2(k-1)=k(k-1)$ must be less than 170, yet $17×16=272>170$, we must have $k=10$, from which we get $c=8$. The sixth house number $a$ is then $c+10=18$ and the answer is (c).